# How to fix "Job for bitnami.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Job for bitnami.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status bitnami.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Answer (score 1):

> Open AWS Lightsail Terminal

```
sudo systemctl status bitnami.service
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo systemctl start bitnami.service
sudo systemctl status bitnami.service
```